# Drupal site is broken due to badly installed module

Tags: drupal, composer-php

I tried to install Simple OAuth (https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth) module in my drupal site running in a shared Godaddy hosting. My first mistake was not to read the installation guide instructing to install the module by using composer. Instead, I installed the module using the Extend=>install a module link within Drupal. Installing the simple_oauth and enabling the module crashed my site and there is no output from the site.

Then I realised there is something wrong with the installation and checked the error log file. The error logged was:
`PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\AccessTokenRepositoryInterface' not found in /home/-----------/public_html/drupal/modules/simple_oauth/src/Repositories/AccessTokenRepository.php on line 10`

At that point I realised there is something wrong with the installation and checked the module instructions which states I should use composer to install the module. I tried to solve this problem by redoing the installation from the ssh by using composer and this command: 
`composer config repositories.drupal composer https://packages.drupal.org/8 && composer require drupal/simple_oauth:^3`
Which did not work because GoDaddy shared hosting plan has only 512mb of rams and composer kills the command because of lack of memory.
I tried reading through and understand how Composer works. There were recommendations saying you should never use composer in a production site and you should run it on your computer and copy the composer.lock file which needs much less rams. I created a PHP server using XAMMP on my computer and copied the composer.json file to my computer and run composer update command in my computer. It downloaded the dependencies and stuff on my computer. And feeling I get the hang of it, I copied the composer.lock file in my drupal server, run composer update command and saw composer delete many stuff which I could not undo.

So my questions are: 1- Is there a way of rescuing this drupal site at this point? I deleted many composer dependencies as far as I can understand. 
The new error log says:
 `PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface' not found in /home/--------/public_html/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernelInterface.php on line 15` 
2- If not, which is fine as I was just beginning to setup the site. Is it possible for someone to explain the best way of handling this scenario? I mean installing a module using composer in a memory critical place. Or explain how composer works for layman. I read about all the dependency stuff but could not figure out how to use it for this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: Well the first thing before installing modules on your site is to backup your db. If something goes wrong, you could easily revert to that db state. Combine this with git  for your code and you can never ruin your site again. However, you're past this point I suppose. Do you use drush or drupal console on your site? This could be a way to easily save your current site.

Comment: For question number 2, if you got memory problems and you can't changed this limit, the easiest alternative is using GIT. Normally dependencies aren't include in your git (because you can install them with composer). Anyhow if you don't put anything in your gitignore, you can pull all your depencies from your repository.

Comment: @Wimanicesir You are right, but sometimes you just forget to backup. Because I was just started I did not set up an automatic backup in my site. But I did not understand your second comment. How can I install some module using GIT in my production server?

Comment: Well, composer doesn't really install anything. It just gets different files containing php that does some functionality. However if you have a local deployment of your site, you can install everything with composer. Once that is done you add absolute everything to your git repository. If you pull this onto your live deployment, dependencies will be 'preinstalled'. I repeat, this is not best practice! But if you have no option to use composer on live, I would recommend this approach.

Comment: I had a very similar problem: crashed Drupal 8.9.5 site after attempt to install Simple OAuth. Just few remarks for those who as well as me know nothing about Composer:
1) You DO NOT need access to your live instance of Drupal.
2) You DO NOT need RUNNING local instance of Drupal as Composer really only downloads and modifies code, not database.
3) You CANNOT install LIBRARIES required by Simple OAuth without Composer (way too complicated).
4) You CAN download code of your live Drupal instance, apply Composer on it and upload it back. It saved my ass in this case.